# Excel sheet values not updated when value changed in DDE Server application

Tags: c#, excel, excel-formula, dde

we're developing real-time data system and its required to implement DDE module to get some data updated in excel sheet while there values changed in our system.

```
-DDE server implemented using Ndde DLL.
1-In system, copy data fiels to ciboard.
2-Open excel in Admin Mode, and paste fields.
-Formula sent to excel like this `= DdeServername|Topic!'item`
-Calling advice method to notify updates.
-Code of handling change written in DDE Server class in `OnAdvise()` Handler
-Issue when updates happen in some system data the excel sheet not updated.
```

what can we do or check to make data update??
Must Excel opened in Admin mode??

Comment: DDE was infamous 20 years ago for failing to do the job in a completely undiagnosable way.  And that was long before firewalls and anti-malware was around.

Comment: So what shall we use? and is there some references to refer?? @HansPassant